# how to add values from database to a list in unity

Tags: c#, sql, unity-game-engine

- i have a data base in which i created a table
  "CampWheelDenominationno", i have a specific row "quota"
- i need to take the "slno" of corresponding "quota" when ever "quota"
  becomes zero.
- my sql code to do that is

  ```
  "select slno from CampWheelDenomination where quota_allowded = 0"
  ```
- now i need to add these "slno" to a list..i have done a method my own but t doesn't works

  ```
  public int checkCodeinDb()
  {


      using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection (connectionString))
      {
          dbConnection.Open ();
          using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand ())
          {
              string sqlQuery = "select slno from CampWheelDenomination where quota_allowded = 0";
              dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
              using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ())
              {
                  while (reader.Read ()) 
                  {
                      //slnolist is a list i have created at begining
                  SlNoList.Add (reader.GetString (0));
                  }

                  return slnolist ; //error at here

              foreach (string st in SlNoList)// i have done this to check whether the slno is added to the list.
              {
                  print (st);
              }


                  dbConnection.Close ();
                  reader.Close ();
              }
          }
      }
  }
  ```

how to add these slno from the databse  to the SlNOList

error is Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to`int' occuring at line  return SlNoList

Comment: What is the error ??

Comment: Where you are defining the `SlNoList`, did you  instantiated that variable?

Comment: slnolist is a list that i have created before

Comment: SlNoList = sql.ExecuteAsList<string>(sqlQuery); will this add the values from database to the list

Comment: @Martinj can you paste the definition of List is you list a list of string?

Comment: @Aatish Sai i have updated the question and error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are trying to trying to return `List` but you function return type is `int`. Change you function definition as follows:

```
public List<string> checkCodeinDb()
{ 
///your usual code here
```

Also looking at your code you probably should have a List inside your function and return it.

Example:

```
List<string> slnolist = checkCodeinDb();

public List<string> checkCodeinDb()
{
List<string> data;
///your usual code here and add your database returned value to data variable and finally return it
return data;
}
```

Comment: Isn't it safer to use `slnolist.addAll(checkCodeinDb());` when the list is already instantiated? Just asking for personal learning :)

Answer (score 0):

and also to add the values from database to list we can use this code

```
public void checkCodeinDb()
{


        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection (connectionString))
        {
            dbConnection.Open ();
            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand ())
            {
                string sqlQuery = "select slno from CampWheelDenomination where quota_allowded = 0";
                dbCmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
                using (IDataReader reader = dbCmd.ExecuteReader ())
                {
                    while (reader.Read ()) 
                    {




                    string ad = reader ["slno"].ToString();

                    SlNoList.Add (ad);

                    }






                foreach (string st in SlNoList)
                {
                    print (st);
                }     





                    dbConnection.Close ();
                    reader.Close ();


                }
            }
        }
    }
```